# How to get access to a parent html element in a child component in Vue3 composition api?

Tags: vuejs3

In my  component i am passing a ref to a component

```
<svg ref="svgContainer" class="circle-svg"></svg>
<TTAGs :svgContainer="svgContainer" />

const svgContainer = ref(null)

// plus other code around these lines
```

In the TTAGs component I'm trying to address it

```
const props = defineProps([ 'svgContainer' ])

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(props.svgContainer)
})
```

but it is null. When i change the svgContainer ref to be a string, the string is console.logged properly, so I suppose the problem is with passing refs as props. How else can I access the svgContainer in my component? I tried through pinia store, but I also failed.
Yes I have seen almost an identical question on stackoverflow, but it wasn't any help for me (options api).

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer. I needed to use nextTick.

```
import { onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  nextTick(() => {
    console.log(props.svgContainer)
  })
})
```